# How can my variable declarations affect execution time

Tags: c++, performance

I am a circuit designer (not a software wizard) and have been working on a numerical algorithm for the past 9 months. As a way to evaluate the effectiveness of my algorithms, I monitor the amount of time needed to converge on a solution.

About 6 months ago I discovered that the way I declare my variables can have a dramatic effect on the time needed for the program to run. For example, simply rearranging the declarations, as shown below, can double the time needed to run the code. Simply changing the lengths of the arrays also affects the problem similarly.

```
int N, j, Iter;
long double RealZero, RealErr, QuadIterErr, QuadX;
long double TUV[3], QuadQP[102], RealQP[102];
bool Updated;

int N, j, Iter;
long double RealZero, RealErr, QuadIterErr, QuadX;
long double QuadQP[102], RealQP[102];
bool Updated;
long double TUV[3];
```

I initially assumed I had some sort of bug, but I can't find it. Other than speed, I don't see any other anomalies, and I get the same results whether the code runs slow or fast.

I found some discussions on problems associated with packing long doubles, but I didn't understand any of it, and they never said how to fix the problem they were discussing.

Can someone give me some insight as to what might be going on here and how to fix it?

I need consistency more than I need the speed. I am not using any speed optimizers (default compiler settings) and I am using C++ Builder XE3. I am not using a #pragma pack (as someone asked).

Based on the comments, I setup the declarations for slow and fast execution, and compared the base addresses on all the long double variables. Whether slow or fast, the addresses end with a 0, 4, 8, or C.

Comment: I would guess cache shenanigans, but I would also guess that an optimizing compiler would rearrange the declarations anyways. By "speed optimizers" do you mean you tell the compiler to not optimize at all?

Comment: Oh, and what length changes did you do?

Comment: With regard to optimizers, I mean that I am simply using the default compiler settings. I can change any of the array lengths and affect the speed, or I can add dummy variables to affect the speed.

Comment: The speed of unoptimized C or C++ code is pretty much completely meaningless.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? AFAIK both gcc and clang default to -O0 (no optimizations), so if you're using one of those I'd say that this is almost certainly something to do with cache/memory

Comment: Is any #pragma pack (or similar) involved?

Comment: If you want consistency, you should pick a specific compiler version, set of flags, and initialization order, and not change them.

Comment: I'll guess that it is some combination of caching and sequential access. For different size arrays, things might also get more complicated with different optimizations for loop tiling.

Comment: Well, OK, but I was hoping to gain an understanding of what causes this.

Comment: The CPU can load (or store) 4 or perhaps 8 bytes in a single cycle, depending on the CPU, etc.  That is, IFF the address being accessed is on a 4 (or 8) byte boundary.  That `bool` (1 byte) you have in there may be causing `TUV` to align inefficiently, losing the speed I mentioned.  If I had to guess, I'd say that is the cause of the problem you see.

Comment: Is there a way to force my variables to land on a 4 (or 8) byte boundary?

Comment: @user5108_Dan: They already do, in general, until you override that. Your compiler is smart. Though, actually, it'd have to be _really really dumb_ to not do that... because it would then have to do _more work_ whenever you access those variables. Aligning to word boundaries is just the obvious and simple thing for a compiler to do. I therefore dispute donjuedo's assessment; more likely it's a more complicated effect on subsequent usage code, involving caching and loop unrolling, as others have said. We couldn't say anything solely from these declarations, which are essentially identical.

Comment: And I agree with the others: rationalising about this with "default compiler settings", _if_ that means no optimisation level, is just pointless. Optimisation is an integral part of the build process -- the compiler is really clever enough to make the program you think it should be making, but if you tell it not to optimise (because you want debugging to be easier, for example) then it's going to stop before its job is finished.

Comment: @donjuedo I rather think, not. Typically the TUV array should be aligned to 8 byte boundary after the bool and not sit on &update+1. No #pragma voodoo assumed.

Comment: @donjuedo isn't the time overhead caused by misalignment suppose to be very little? I mean, it's only 7 bytes padding, so that can't double the run time, IMO

Comment: @CIsForCookies, If 8 bytes are loaded one by one, instead of 8 at a time, that portion of the work goes up eight-fold.  There is obviously more work that just moving `TUV` elements around.  I could believe it averages out to double time overall.  I will experiment at home tonight (Ubuntu), just to satisfy my curiosity -- I'd rather not assume.

Comment: @donjuedo I don't understand what you mean by loading the bytes one by one. The pc reads word size number of bytes each cycle, is it not? I would appreciate if you could elaborate, or share your experiment results

Comment: @CIsForCookies Unless you count memory latency, L1, L2, L3 cache (line) size and associativity, memory access coalescing, pipelining, the various DDR switching latencies, memory bandwidth, stores omitted completely (e.g. due to the fact that they are "done to a register"), etc. pp.

Comment: @donjuedo [It ain't as simple as you believe](http://www.alexonlinux.com/aligned-vs-unaligned-memory-access)

Comment: @gha.st, Thanks for the link.  That's a good article.  In brief, he says the alignment I referred to is not the cause, the allocated alignment relative to a cache line boundary is.  The core idea is the same, just harder to run into nowadays with cache line boundaries much farther apart.  His conclusion:  "To be on the safe side, try to keep your data structures memory aligned, always."

Answer (score 1):

One thing that definitely *does* affect code performance is unaligned data: the x86 platform can read unaligned data (unlike some other architectures), but will suffer a performance penalty.

What is an unaligned access? When the size of the type is not stored at an address that is a multiple of that size. So if you store a 32-bit integer at an odd address, or even at an even address that isn't a multiple of 4, the CPU may have to do two memory reads to get both halves of the data.

In this case, the size of `long double` is 8, so you'd want them to be stored at addresses with a multiple of 8 - but the first three variables are integers, making 12, so in the first block of definitions **all** of the long doubles are stored at non-aligned memory addresses.

The second block of definitions given don't seem to be too different - but the `bool` has moved up, making `TUV` fully aligned now. If `TUV` was the most heavily used memory in the algorithm, then I could well believe that there was a timing difference!

So how do you fix it? Either tell the compiler to store variables at a greater alignment (note this is *not* to do with packing - that has to do with storage within a structure), or at the very least put all the largest-typed variables first in the declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you can see, I asked this about a year ago, so it is going to take me a while to ressurect the code (from an archive) to test your answer.

Answer (score 0):

user5108_Dan said:

> With regard to optimizers, I mean that I am simply using the default compiler settings. I can change any of the array lengths and affect the speed, or I can add dummy variables to affect the speed.

This is most likely your problem. Since production code will *always* be optimised, do not do your speed tests on unoptimised code: you will essentially be doing the compiler's work!